# How to allow an app on a specific interface?

Tags: ufw

I have a network interface `my_very_important_vpn` and a ufw app `tensorboard`:

```
$ sudo ufw app info tensorboard
Profile: tensorboard
Title: Tensorboard
Description: Tensorboard - a web application for tracking training of
neural networks.

Port:
  6006/tcp
```

I want ufw to allow it only on the interface `my_very_important_vpn`. How do I do that?

Comment: In the app, bind the socket to a specific interface.  Or in ufw, drop packets to port 6006 on all other interfaces.

Comment: By "in the app", do you mean the tensorboard program itself rather than ufw's app file for tensorboard?

Comment: In the tensorboard program it calls bind on a socket to receive packets.  At that time it can bind to all interfaces or a specific interface.  If you don't have control over that, then you'll need to use ufw to filter unwanted packets.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have control over that.

Comment: Then should be something like `sudo ufw allow from <vpn_network> to any port 6006`  Where `<vpn_network>` is `192.168.5.0/24`  or whatever is your VPN IP/mask.

Comment: Yes, indeed, there is something like that. Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to use something like that with a ufw app config.